# Ubuntu Server 20.04 multi-boot install?

Tags: dual-boot, server, grub2, system-installation, grub-efi

I attempted to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a specified partition (/dev/sda5), with GRUB already having been installed on the EFI system partition at /dev/sda1 (*i.e.*, installed to /dev/sda, which is a GPT disk, and this is a UEFI system, so GRUB is on /dev/sda1 (not the MBR or a BIOS boot partition)), and other OSs on /dev/sda2-4.

The problem is, the installer would not permit specification of the partition where /boot should be mounted / installed.  Presumably, one should specify /dev/sda1 in this case but the installer would not permit it, leaving the "Next" button greyed out, among other things.

One imagines this would be an especially simple thing to do but the installer doesn't seem capable of it and no obvious documentation or help seems to exist on the topic.

Obviously, with other OSs installed, the Microsoft (*i.e.*, "wipe-everything") approach isn't available, never mind excusable.

How does one install Ubuntu Server to a specified partition when GRUB exists on the ESP?

More specifically, how does one satisfy the /boot assignment step in the installer, so as to begin the installation?

Comment: Do not confuse a /boot which must be ext2 or ext4 formatted with an ESP which must be FAT32 formatted. Some server installs may need a /boot, but desktops typically do not. You always install grub to a drive like sda, not a partition like sda1. But with UEFI, the installer will find & use the ESP, one per drive/device. Last install will be grub in control, if you want different grub you have to manage that.

Comment: @oldfred, thanks.  I understand about ESPs, their formatting, and the location and installation of GRUB thereon.  I simply was describing the partition layout, which includes that the ESP is /dev/sda1.  With grub-efi, the command is to install it on the drive as you say but it ends up in the ESP and not the MBR (or a BIOS boot partition).  Also, as stated in the OP, I have no need to install GRUB because it already is installed.  Misapprehensions aside, the question is how to satisfy the /boot partition designation in the installer so as to proceed with the installation.

Comment: @oldfred, also, the installer requires specification of a partition in assigning /boot; it isn't assigned to the drive.  Again, the question is specifically what to specify for the /boot location in this step while running the installer (if that is possible), or otherwise how to proceed with the installation.

Comment: Do not use server, and have not done a server test install recently with new version installer. Is this an LVM install as that often wants a separate /boot? Otherwise I thought it was like the Desktop I use and /boot  partition is optional. With second desktop installs, I install grub to a throw away location, second drive's ESP. Desktop that uses Ubiquity also can use -u parameter to not install grub. Do not know if available with server version.

Comment: No, it's not an LVM install.  The machine has two volumes, one on an SSD and a second on a HDD.  Hacking the /boot assignment by putting it in a throwaway partition isn't a bad idea.  It adds a step, of manually removing the new /boot and perhaps editing fstab, but it might get it done.  Of course, the installer should anticipate this in the first place and skip creating useless configurations that must be undone.  Still, it's a hack.  I'll post back with results, although the failure returned the project to the end of the queue, so it may be some time.